# How is this algebraic expression turned into positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have no idea how to expression below can be turned into the lower expression. Which rule or concept am I missing?

$$\frac{-2a^2-2a-2b-8}{16+8b-a^2+b^2}$$

How can this expand into the following:

$$\frac{2a^2+2a+2b+8}{a^2-b^2-8b-16}$$

Comment: A factor of negative one has been collected from the numerator and denominator, which has then been cancelled, quite like any other common factor between the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply and divide the numerator and denominator by $\frac{-1}{-1}$
$$\frac{(-2a^2-2a-2b-8)(-1)}{(16+8b-a^2+b^2)(-1)}=\frac{2a^2+2a+2b+8}{a^2-b^2-8b-16}$$

Comment: Thanks you, why would I want to do that? I am pretty new to math, what is the idea behind it?

Comment: Because, if you multiply with $-1$ all the negative terms will turn positive and positive will turn negative. Same applies for the denominatior

Comment: Sorry I mean, why would I want to turn the numerator positive and turn the denominator negative? (with the exception of a^2)

Comment: You can solve even without turning numerator into positive

Answer (score 1):

mutiply the expression with $$\frac{-1}{-1}$$